# How to set a decision tree in Matlab

Tags: matlab, probability, decision-tree

I had set classification trees in R but this time, I want to set a regression tree like in the picture[image: decision tree], the thing is I have to do it in Matlab and it is not like the classification tree so I would need some help. Now, let *b* as a constant number that could be set in 0 or 20, so we got the probably to set the same number o plus one (this could be solve with a `for`). Then each path has its own probabilities which I got in a vector which has the empirical distribution of the case, and the values could be set in another vector. So I have seen some regression trees code but they don't take in count the probabilities. Needless to say that the tree should pick the path with greater benefit, so the objective is to set *b* as that number.
I wrote as good as I could,given that english is not my native language.